# Comparison of two object, that have the same anchestor

Tags: python, inheritance, operators, comparison-operators

I have 3 classes:
`Person`, `Teacher(Person)` and `Student(Person)` and I need to compare its object.

What I'm doing:

```
class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, year_of_birth, age):
        super().__init__(name, year_of_birth, age)
        self.skill= skill

    def __eq__(self, st1):
        if self.age == st1.age:
            return True
        return False

    def __lt__(self, st1):
        if self.age < st1.age:
            return True
        return False

    def __gt__(self, st1):
        if self.age > st1. age:
            return True
        return False
```

And the same actions in 'Teacher(Person)' class to compare teacher by their count of years of experience.
And now I want to compare objects of classes 'Student' and 'Teacher' like

```
student1 == teacher1
```

and I shoud get 'False' because they cannot be compared (students are compared by age, teachers - by experience)

I'm trying this in my 'Person' class:

```
    def __eq__(self, person2):
        if self.__class__.__name__ == person2.__class__.__name__:
            return True
        return False
```

but when I call 'print(student1 == teacher2)' I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User1\PycharmProjects\university\main.py", line 95, in <module>
    print(student1 == teacher2)
  File "C:\Users\User1\PycharmProjects\university\main.py", line 71, in __eq__
    if self.years_of_experience == teacher2.years_of_experience:
AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'years_of_experience'
```

Any advices how to compare those two objects correctly and get False, because they are objects of different classes and cannot be compared (according to my task)?

Comment: Check the type of the second argument in `Student.__eq__` and `Teacher.__eq__`.

Comment: `Person.__eq__` is not going to be called if you override it in subclasses, unless you explicitly call it via `super().__eq__(other)`…

Comment: So do I understand correctly, that I don't need to override `__eq__` in my `Person` class? I have to check the class in `__eq__` method of my `Student` and `Teacher` classes, right?

Comment: You could check the general class in `Person.__eq__`, and then make a more specific additional check in the subclasses; but again, you'll need to call `Person.__eq__` explicitly too. Something like `return super().__eq__(other) and self... == other..`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've deleted `__eq__` from my `Person` class and added some logic to overrided methods in `Teacher` and `Student` classes. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 1):

Remove **eq** method from the Person class. Implement **eq** for Student and Teacher.

Comment: Thank you, than worked for me! I've deleted `__eq__` from my` Person` class and added some logic to overrided methods in `Teacher` and `Student` classes.